# Quickbooks integration on website

Tags: integration, quickbooks

After searching online for some guides on how to integrate quickbooks with our webshop I have yet to find a solution that fits what we need.

Currently we are running Quickbooks Enterprise Desktop on a VPS.
We have the website hosted on another VPS. The website is running .NET 4.0.

We need to show the actual inventory stock on our products - pulled live from quickbooks.
We also need our customers to be able to change their details (delivery address and so on).
Lastly we need any new orders on our website to be automatically entered into quickbooks.

From my understanding we need to install Quickbooks Web connector on our VPS that run quickbooks. The quickbooks SDK on the VPS that runs the website, and set up the Web connector to connect to a webservice we create on the VPS that runs the website...

First off, is this correct?

Secondly, from what I can read the Quickbook Web Connector will perform a series of tasks at a given interval (update socks, add new invoices and so on). Is there any way this can happen live?

That is, my website can query Quickbooks through the webconnector when I want it to?

Any pointers, guides, examples will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding we need to install Quickbooks Web connector on
>   our VPS that run quickbooks.

Yes.

> The quickbooks SDK on the VPS that runs
>   the website,

If you want to, but it's not strictly necessary.

The SDK has some tools which are helpful for debugging, but it's not *required* at all.

> and set up the Web connector to connect to a webservice
>   we create on the VPS that runs the website...

Yes.

> Secondly, from what I can read the Quickbook Web Connector will
>   perform a series of tasks at a given interval (update socks, add new
>   invoices and so on). Is there any way this can happen live?

Correct, the Web Connector updates at intervals.

Using the Web Connector, there is no way to make it real-time/live. You could, however, write your own version/replacement of the Web Connector, and make it real-time/live if you wanted to.

Be aware, however, that QuickBooks is not the greatest choice for real-time communication. There are a number of scenarios where it is *impossible* to communicate with QuickBooks. Thus, you might not want to tie your the functionality of your website too tightly to the availability of QuickBooks. Consider:

- If more than one QuickBooks company file is open at a time, QuickBooks will not allow integrated applications to exchange data with QuickBooks
- If QuickBooks has recently auto-updated itself, it will not allow integrated applications to exchange data with it until a reboot
- If QuickBooks is in single-user mode, it will not allow integrated applications to exchange data with it
- Make sure that QuickBooks performs quickly enough to query the data you need in real-time

Generally speaking, you're better off using the Web Connector to query data every few minutes, than depending on QuickBooks always being available.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll dig more into the web connector and make it export the data to the local website database and pull the data from there on page generation.

Answer (score 0):

We just helped a customer with a project (custom internally facing web app) that needed to integrate with on-prem QuickBooks Enterprise and some other things. We used Appsynergy's federated stuff and it worked great.